# How to restrict screen reader to not read a certain text?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

Imagine, I have a `<div>` with `aria-label` as "Read this" (`aria-label` is added at runtime). Inside the `<div>`, I have a `<span>` with text "do not read this".

Now what Jaws is doing is, it reads both the text ("Read this" and "do not read this").

```html
<div aria-label="Read this">
  <span>Do not read this</span>
</div>
```

The expectation is to only read "Read this". Is there anyway to restrict screen readers to force stop reading a text?

Comment: "Now what Jaws is doing is, it reads both the text ("Read this" and "do not read this")." I would be interested to know what JAWS version and browser/version you are using to get this result. using this test case https://s.codepen.io/stevef/debug/deVXag JAWS 2018 does not read the aria-label in Firefox/Chrome/IE as I would expect. Refer to https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/#label-support

Comment: @SteveFaulkner Jaws 2018 and Chrome 66.0

Comment: I have retested this using https://codepen.io/stevef/pen/deVXag as previously and I cannot get JAWS 2018 and Chrome 66 to read the aria-label

Answer (score 8):

`aria-hidden="true"` is the thing you want

```
<div aria-label="Read this">
<span aria-hidden="true">Do not read this</span>
</div>
```

**Note that not all screenreaders will read the `aria-label` on a `div` element and that it will result in a blank element**

Comment: I tried this. But it is not working in chrome using screenreader JAWS

Comment: `aria-hidden` is supported on all screen readers and browsers and is the correct answer.  I just tried it with jaws2018 and chrome and jaws will completely skip the element when using the virtual cursor (up/down arrow) as @Adam states.  I then gave the `<div>` a few random roles so that its accessible name could be computed and all I heard was "read this" so it's working as you want.  However, my test case used Adam's code as is.  I didn't programmatically add the `aria-label` to the `<div>` as your OP states.

Comment: "I then gave the <div> a few random roles so that its accessible name could be computed and all I heard was "read this" so it's working as you want." Yes the `aria-label` will be announced when certain roles are used. But you need to be careful to use a role that makes sense for the semantics, not just add a role to get the `aria-label` to be announced.

Answer (score 0):

works for JAWS 2018, chrome 72:

```html
<div role="text" aria-label="Read this">
Do not read this
</div>
```

Comment: `role="text"` is not an "officially" supported role.  It often works but you have to be careful if you use it.  Support for it is spotty and for screen reader + browser combinations that currently work, it could easily stop working in the next version.  If you are trying to be WCAG compliant, using `role="text"` will be flagged as an error in the html parser (https://html5.validator.nu/), thus violating WCAG 4.1.1.